# How to show specific value from array with mustache?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mustache, mustache.php

I have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 1
            [value] => Value 1
            [id] => 1428735262
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 2
            [value] => Value 2
            [id] => 2428735262
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title 3
            [value] => Value 3
            [id] => 3428735262
        )

)
```

With mustache I am able to iterate overall of them using:

```
{{#values}}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    {{{value}}}
{{/values}}
```

But what if I only want to show specific value, for example only second element of the array (one with Title 2)?

I tried like:

```
{{#values}}
{{#2428735262}}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    {{{value}}}
{{/2428735262}}
{{/values}}
```

and:

```
{{#values.2428735262}}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    {{{value}}}
{{/values.2428735262}}
```

But none worked. Does anyone know how to get **specific item from array** ?

PS. I am using PHP version of mustache. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
{{values.1.value}}
```

Read more at:

> https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Variable-Resolution